# In D3 Arrow is not calling based on the condition

Tags: d3.js, svg

In my code I am tryng to link few svg rect elements with arrow (svg markers) based on the conditions in my d3 application. The rects are creating without any issues but no arrow is generating. But similar approach is working in my other examples. 
Here is my code:

```
  var rect = canvas.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
    .filter(condition) 
    .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x + 20 ; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 30 ; })
    .attr("width", 30)
    .attr("height", 30)
    .attr("opacity", 0.25);
```

Code for arrow and the line:

```
    //Create definition for arrowhead:
     rect.append("defs").append("marker")
    .attr("id", "arrowhead")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 0)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerUnits", "strokeWidth")
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
     ....
     // Connecting the arrow and the line (not working)
     rect.selectAll("rect").append("line")
    .filter(condition)
    .attr("x1", function(d) { getting x1 values })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {getting y1 values })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {getting x2 values)
    .attr("y2", function(d) {getting y2 values)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrowhead)")
    .attr("fill", "none");
```

Any idea how it will generate all the arrows..

Comment: The `defs` element needs to be appended to the SVG, not the `rect` elements.

Comment: I also did the change but now only one arrow is displaying not all of them. Now When I am checking my filter as console output it shows the correct filters...

Comment: This is my code and when I am calling it from the code it gives me the last value (does it the reason for this issue).. The code is to get the coordinates of the rect:                                     var getSize;
var rectPos = document.getElementsByTagName("rect");
for(i=0; i<rectPos.length; i++){
getSize = rectPos[i].getBBox();
}                                                                  and my calling way is:                                       .attr("x1", function(d) {return getSize.x; })...

Comment: If you want different arrows for all the links, you need to create separate `marker` elements with separate IDs.

Comment: thanks it works but I needed to create vars for the svg line and it works..

Answer (score 0):

if I understood well you'll need to draw an arrow nest to a rect, try with this definition:

```
svg.append('defs').append('marker')
.attr('id', 'arrow').attr('viewBox', '0 0 10 10')
.attr('refX', 10).attr('refY', 5)
.attr('markerUnits', 'strokeWidth')
.attr('markerWidth', 8)
.attr('markerHeight', 6)
.attr('orient', 'auto')
.append('path')
.attr('d', 'M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z');
```

and append it in the enter event

```
var rect = canvas.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
    .filter(condition) 
    .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x + 20 ; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 30 ; })
    .attr("width", 30)
    .attr("height", 30)
    .attr("opacity", 0.25)
    .append('line')
    .attr('class','path')
    .attr('marker-end','url(#arrow)');
```

Comment: thank you I changed the code but it does not make any difference. There is no output and in the console there were no issues...

Comment: I did something similar of what you are doing, take a look to this fiddle I got some inspiration from there http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/89/

Comment: thanks!! I already tried this approach from forced layout but when I am using multiple layouts I am not able to control all the elements so I moved to this simple approach..